# ブラウザの「戻る」ボタンを押したら（リロードしたら）、記述のjavascriptが効かないようにしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
var flg=true;
setTimeout("redirect()", 1000);
function redirect(){
  if(flg){
    flg=false;
    location.href='http://www.yahoo.co.jp/';
  }
}
</script>
```

index.htmlに上記のjavascriptを記述して、index.htmlにアクセスしたら1秒でヤフーに飛ぶようにしているのですが、ヤフーにいる状態でブラウザの「戻る」ボタンをクリックしたら
またindex.htmlから1秒でヤフーに飛んでしまうので、その処理を止めたいです。
（ブラウザの「戻る」ボタンを押したら、上述のscriptが効かないようにしたい）
ローカルだとうまく動作するのですが、サーバーアップすると上述のscriptはずっと効いていて...。どのようにscript書けばいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

履歴に残す URL にはハッシュを付けて置き、そのハッシュを付けた URL でのアクセスではリダイレクトさせない、という方法です。

```javascript
window.addEventListener("unload", function(){
    // 移動する際、履歴には #no-redirect 付きの URL を残す
    history.replaceState(undefined, document.title, "#no-redirect");
});

if(window.location.hash == "#no-redirect"){
    // 履歴経由のアクセスの可能性が高いので、リダイレクトはしない
    // ユーザには #no-redirect 抜きの URL を露出
    history.replaceState(undefined, document.title, window.location.pathname);
}
else{
    // 履歴経由のアクセスではなさそうなので、リダイレクト
    setTimeout(redirect, 1000);
}

function redirect(){
    window.location.assign("http://example.com/");
}
```

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます！ただ、この方法を実行させたところ、iPhoneのsafariではリダイレクト自体しなくなってしまい...。 調べたところiOSのsafariでは"unload"イベントが効かないことが原因なようなのですが、他に解決策ありますでしょうか。。。

Comment: @lark  `pagehide`の方が最新のブラウザでは広く[サポートされている](http://caniuse.com/#search=pagehide)のかも知れないですね。

Comment: @lark いや、リダイレクトしないという事は `window.location` が動かない問題ですね。`window` 無しならなぜか動くとか、`document` の方にはあるとか、そんな感じではなかったでしょうか。

Comment: @mjy様 申し訳ありません、iphoneのsafariでは「リダイレクト自体しない」ではなく、「リダイレクトはするが、元のページに戻れなくなってしまう」の間違いでした。 unload を pagehide に変えても現象は変わらずでして。。。

Comment: @mjy様 iphoneの時のみ、質問に記載したscriptを実行するようにし、その他のデバイスでアクセスした時は@mjy様に教えて頂いたscriptを実行するようにしたら、上手く遷移しそうです！